# ionic3 - active tab changing from text to icon

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, tabs, ionic3

[image]
This is my tabs screenshot, ios and android version. I want the last tab`(tab4Root)` when I clicked it, change to icon `cart`.

**tabs.html**

```
<ion-tabs color="danger">
  <ion-tab [root]="tab1Root" tabTitle="新闻" tabIcon="ios-globe-outline"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab2Root" tabTitle="SOS" tabIcon="call"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab3Root" tabTitle="服务" tabIcon="people"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab4Root" tabTitle="唐人街"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

**tabs.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { NewsPage } from '../news/news';
import { SosPage } from '../sos/sos';
import { ServicesPage } from '../services/services';
import { ShopPage } from '../shop/shop';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'tabs.html'
})
export class TabsPage {
  // this tells the tabs component which Pages
  // should be each tab's root Page
  tab1Root: any = NewsPage;
  tab2Root: any = SosPage;
  tab3Root: any = ServicesPage;
  tab4Root: any = ShopPage;

  constructor() {

  }
}
```

Comment: @SurajRao Do you have any solutions???

Comment: tabs are designed to hold the navigation stacks.. dont think you can alter them dynamically

Comment: So it's not possible to do like when user clicked tabs change from `text` to `icon`?

Comment: not sure.. havent figured out any workaround yet..tried dynamically setting but didnt seem to work

Comment: Ok..thanks..you can write your answer down and I will mark it

Comment: ? I dont have a solution... can add if I find a workaround..  you could too

Comment: @SurajRao Did you found any solution now?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<ion-tabs color="danger">
<ion-tab [root]="tab1Root" tabTitle="新闻" tabIcon="ios-globe-outline"></ion-tab>
<ion-tab [root]="tab2Root" tabTitle="SOS" tabIcon="call"></ion-tab>
<ion-tab [root]="tab3Root" tabTitle="服务" tabIcon="people"></ion-tab>
<ion-tab [root]="tab4Root" tabTitle="唐人街" tabIcon="cart"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

Comment: Sorry.. I want when I haven't clicked showing text only, when I clicked this tab showing icon 'cart'